# How to upload a file in Flutter firebase and show it

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have searched a lot on uploading a file in firebase in flutter ,but none of them are working properly .
basically i want to select a file from my device and upload it to firebase and retrieve that file and show on screen .
Also i am new to flutter so i dont know how to handel permission for my SD card.
So can someone please show me the basic code required to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Basically these are the steps you need to follow (Assuming you've already connected your app to Firebase):

1. Implement `file_picker`: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

```
    File file = await FilePicker.getFile();
```

(Add `getFile()` to a button during implementation)

2. Upload file to Firebase Storage:

```
StorageReference str = FirebaseStorage.instance
           .ref()
           .child('Files');
//Uploading
StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
           str.putFile(file);
//Getting download URL to save in database
String downloadURL =
           await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

3. Save `downloadURL` to Firebase Realtime Database:

```
realtimedb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('FileLink');
realtimedb.set(downloadURL);
```

4. Now to retrieve this you need to fetch the file link:

```
String dURL;
await realtimedb.instance
.reference()
.once()
.then((snapshot){dURL=snapshot.value;});
```

5. Finally, depending on the type of file it is you can perform further steps to display it. For example, if it's an image you can use `Image.network()` to display it on your app. You have the link of the file in `dURL` so you can use it to access the file.